# Symfony2.8.48 Installed Successfully,but server could not start on windows10:testing commands php app/console server:run,php bin/console server:run

Tags: symfony

1. List item

**C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox>php app/console server:run**

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension.php on line 326
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\app\console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\app\console:27
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:117
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:62
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:131
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:507
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->prepareContainer() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:600
PHP   8. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle->getContainerExtension() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:619
PHP   9. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle->createContainerExtension() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle.php:77
PHP  10. class_exists() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle.php:208
PHP  11. Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle.php:0

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension.php on line 326

Call Stack:
    0.0005     234536   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\app\console:0
    0.0565    2067176   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\app\console:27
    0.0694    2338448   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:117
    0.0695    2338712   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:62
    0.0882    2616632   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:131
    0.0955    2692280   6. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:507
    0.1374    3233328   7. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->prepareContainer() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:600
    0.1940    4338728   8. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle->getContainerExtension() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:619
    0.1940    4338984   9. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle->createContainerExtension() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle.php:77
    0.1941    4339264  10. class_exists() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle.php:208
    0.1941    4339808  11. Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass() C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle.php:0

**C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\nnokox>php bin/console server:run**

Could not open input file: bin/console

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because you're using php version older than 5.5 which introduced the `::class` support which your php complains about.

The second error means exactly what it says, the `bin/console` file does not exist, that's because it does not exist with Symfony 2.

Comment: hello so am i suppose to downgrade my php version ? please if you can send me a url link or youtube link on how to downgrade my php version...thanks i do really appreciate